# Trouble deploying Grails 5.1.1 app on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, grails

I have created a Grails 5.1.1 app from the command line with "grails create-app".

It runs fine, from the command line "grails run-app", and I can build a war file which can be run from the command line with "java -jar app-0.1.war".

I then attempted to follow the instructions for deploying in a container (Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9 in my case) by adding the context-path and changing the build dependency. The [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/5.1.1/guide/single.html#deployingAnApplication) says to change "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat" to provided in build.gradle. "provided" is not a valid option as far as I can tell. I've tried both providedCompile and providedRuntime with the same result as below.

When I deploy the resulting app-0.1-plain.war I get one of two errors:

```
The bean 'characterEncodingFilter' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servl
et/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

with the suggested remedy of adding: spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
results in a circular bean reference for hibernateDatastore.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I'm using openjdk version "1.8.0_292" of Java, Gradle 7.2 and I tried deploying on apache-tomcat-8.5.73 and apache-tomcat-9.0.56.

Any ideas about what might be wrong with my set up that prevents the deploy war from running?

**Edit**: This seems to be a manifestation:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12288 and/or
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12278

Though the work around suggested did not work for me I do not experience the same problem with 5.0.3 as suggested in 12278.

Comment: "provided is not a valid option as far as I can tell. " - I believe that provided is a valid option.  I don't think the dependency scope is the cause of the problem described in the question.

Comment: Thanks. The grails build process fails with "provided" with the following error:

> Could not find method provided() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

But, yeah, I don't think this dependency is the issue.

Comment: The issue seems related to https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12288

Comment: @Roland Apologies.  I had overlooked the version of Grails you are using.

Comment: @PuneetBehl Thanks. I have noted such in my latest edit.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown No worries. Thanks for having a look.